# Collection of objects in classic ASP using VBScript?

Tags: collections, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a class called 'Company' that has properties like 'CompanyName', 'CompanyCode' and 'IsActive'. This class is in VBScript. I want to store a collection of Company objects using VBScript in classic ASP. Is this possible, and if yes, then how would I do it?

Comment: Arrays are pretty basic.. what is your final goal? What will you do with that collection?

Comment: I need to be able to loop through the Company objects and create dynamic strings based on Company properties. For example, create a comma delimited list of CompanyIds based on Company objects in the dictionary collection.

Comment: So Guido answer below should be what you're looking for, isn't it?

Comment: Did my answer work for you? If so, could you tag it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use an array or a dictionary object:

**Array**

```
' create an array with a fixed size
dim companies(2) 

' fill the array with the companies
set companies(0) = Company1 
set companies(1) = Company2
set companies(2) = Company3

' iteration example 1
dim company
for each company in companies
    response.write company.CompanyName
next

' iteration example 2
dim i
for i = 0 to ubound(companies)
    response.write companies(i).CompanyName
next
```

**Dictionary**

```
' create a dictionary object
dim companies
set companies = server.createObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

' add the companies
companies.add "Key1", Company1
companies.add "Key2", Company2
companies.add "Key3", Company3

' iteration example
dim key
for each key in companies.keys
    response.write key & " = " & companies.item(key).CompanyName
next
```