# Creating an Array of Objects in Classic ASP

Tags: arrays, asp-classic

I am trying to create a class in Classic ASP and am getting close to what I am looking for but it is not quite there. I have yet to find any examples that solve my problem.

In the example I need the LineItem class to be stored in the Order class as an array so there can be multiple line items for an order. Currently it works but only allows a single instance of LineItem. Can someone give me an example showing me how to make it into an array? I understand how to create an array of obects, but not how to store them in the parent object. My apologies, but it has been over 15 years since I have done any programming in Classic ASP and I have forgotten most of what I knew back then.

```
<%
    Class LineItem

    Private LineNumberVar
    Private ItemCostVar
    Private QuantityVar
    Private ItemCodeVar
    Private ItemDescriptionVar

    ' Line Number
    Public Property Get LineNumber()
        LineNumber = LineNumberVar
    End Property

    Public Property Let LineNumber(lineNumberParam)
        LineNumberVar = lineNumberParam
    End Property

    ' Item Cost
    Public Property Get ItemCost()
        ItemCost = ItemCostVar
    End Property

    Public Property Let ItemCost(itemCostParam)
        ItemCostVar = itemCostParam
    End Property

    ' Quantity
    Public Property Get Quantity()
        Quantity = QuantityVar
    End Property

    Public Property Let Quantity(quantityParam)
        QuantityVar = quantityParam
    End Property

    ' Item Code
    Public Property Get ItemCode()
        ItemCode = ItemCodeVar
    End Property

    Public Property Let ItemCode(itemCodeParam)
        ItemCodeVar = itemCodeParam
    End Property

    ' Item Description
    Public Property Get ItemDescription()
        ItemDescription = ItemDescriptionVar
    End Property

    Public Property Let ItemDescription(itemDescriptionParam)
        ItemDescriptionVar = itemDescriptionParam
    End Property
End Class


Class Order

    Private CustomerIDVar
    Private OrderIDVar
    Private EmailVar
    Private ItemsVar 

    'CustomerID
    Public Property Get CustomerID()
        CustomerID = CustomerIDVar
    End Property

    Public Property Let CustomerID(customerIDParam)
        CustomerIDVar = customerIDParam
    End Property

    'OrderID
    Public Property Get OrderID()
        OrderID = OrderIDVar
    End Property

    Public Property Let OrderID(orderIDParam)
        OrderIDVar = orderIDParam
    End Property

    'Email
    Public Property Get Email()
        Email = EmailVar
    End Property

    Public Property Let Email(emailParam)
        EmailVar = emailParam
    End Property

    ' Line Items (needs to be an array of LineItem class objects)
    'Items
    Public Property Get Items()
        Set Items = ItemsVar
    End Property

    ' must use Set for objects
    Public Property Set Items(itemsParam)
        Set ItemsVar = itemsParam
    End Property

    Private Sub Class_Initialize
        ItemsVar = Array() ' initialize to empty dynamic array
    End Sub

    Function AddLineItem(itemArray, item)
        ReDim Preserve itemArray(UBound(itemArray) + 1)
        itemArray(UBound(itemArray)) = items
        AddLineItem = itemArray
    End Function
End Class


    Dim ItemsVar
    Set ItemsVar = new LineItem

    ItemsVar.LineNumber = 1
    ItemsVar.ItemCost = 25.00
    ItemsVar.Quantity = 1
    ItemsVar.ItemCode = "42667"
    ItemsVar.ItemDescription = "Software"

    Dim OrderVar
    Set OrderVar = New Order

    Set OrderVar.Items = ItemsVar

    OrderVar.CustomerID = "0937263"
    OrderVar.OrderID = "2348725"
    OrderVar.Email = "nobody@gmail.com"

    %>

    <%= OrderVar.CustomerID %><br />
    <%= OrderVar.OrderID %><br />
    <%= OrderVar.Email %><br />
    <%= OrderVar.Items.LineNumber %><br />
    <%= OrderVar.Items.ItemCost %><br />
    <%= OrderVar.Items.Quantity %><br />
    <%= OrderVar.Items.ItemCode %><br />
    <%= OrderVar.Items.ItemDescription %><br />
```

Comment: It's just an implementation problem. This might set you on the right path: https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1499665

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Collection of objects in classic ASP using VBScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014986/collection-of-objects-in-classic-asp-using-vbscript)

Comment: Lankey - That post explains how to create a collection of objects, but I am having trouble figuring out how to store that in a parent object. Ideally there would be an AddLineItem method where I could keep adding new line item objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you need only to add a lineitem to the array, you can make the `AddLineItem` a sub instead of a function.

```
Class Order

    Private ItemsVar 

    Public Property Get Items()
        Items = ItemsVar
    End Property

    Public Property Set Items(itemsParam)
        Set ItemsVar = itemsParam
    End Property

    Private Sub Class_Initialize
        ItemsVar = Array()
    End Sub

    Sub AddLineItem(newitem)
        ReDim Preserve ItemsVar(UBound(ItemsVar) + 1)
        set ItemsVar(UBound(ItemsVar)) = newitem
    End Sub

End Class
```

To add a new lineitem,

```
Set OrderVar = New Order
Ordervar.AddLineItem(NewItem)
```

To loop through the lineitems,

```
For each ThisLineItem in OrderVar.Items
    Response.write ThisLineItem.ItemDescription & "<br>"
Next
```